# Convert UTC ISO value to `String` (Text)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Objective: I need to convert a UTC value (col A) to a `String` before passing it to a function for local time zone conversion.

Errors: no errors, script runs successfully

Issue: Time is not converted to specified time zone

Further info:

If I use the following in my `LOCALTIME` function, the date is converted correctly.

```
var originalDate = new Date("2020-05-12T23:22:46.120Z");
```

[image]

Function to get the time in UTC (col A):

```
function getAllEmailAndDiningPreferences(changeType){

  var orders = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Orders');

  var ordersData = orders.getDataRange().getValues();

  var lr = getLastRow(orders, "A1:E");

  for (var i=0; i<lr; i++){

    if(ordersData[i][1].length == 0){ 


      var orderId = ordersData[i][0]; //note: need to convert 'orderId' to a String

      var email = getEmailFromOrderedId(orderId.toString()); //toString() doesn't convert it to a expected String

      convertOrderDateToLocalTimeZone(i+1, orderId);
      i+1;

    }

  }

}
```

Function to convert to locatime zone:

```
function LOCALTIME(datetimeString) {

   if (datetimeString.map) {    

    return datetimeString.map(LOCALTIME); 

  } else {

    var originalDate = new Date(datetimeString);
    return Utilities.formatDate(originalDate, "Australia/Adelaide", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")

  }

}
```

Comment: Happy to have a look but the way you wrote it sounds like you're just asking for a free "programming service".
What's the purpose of the picture? Is that the target? Are you getting an error message? Can you extract the relevant lines? Right now it's just a code dump with no generality.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer the screenshot are the UTC ISO values that I am trying to convert using my `LOCALTIME` function. I have updated my question with more information as to what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Why don't you just store the times as unix time stamps and let your Sheet and Script locales deal with the timezones for you?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I wish it was that easy...these times are written by an app and I have no control over it.

Comment: In what format does the app write the times, and in what time zone?

Comment: format is UTC ISO timezone I dont know. I simply need to convert the UTC ISO time to a `String` and that works, I just don't know how, I have tried `.toString()` but that doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean by `that doesn't work`?

Comment: `function LOCALTIME(datetimeString)` expects a string text, but what I have is a UTC ISO value in a variable called `orderId`, trying to convert it to a text by using `orderId.toString()` doesnt do it

Comment: Try `new Date(orderId).toString()`

Comment: didn't work :/ , how can i convert the UTC value to Text?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214742/discussion-between-rafa-guillermo-and-roggie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Due to Sheet locale, you need to get the display value of the cell before making a date object so that the Script project reads it correctly as UTC.*

#### More Information:

`getDisplayValues()` will literally get the values of the cells as you see them in the UI. As a result, as the strings are inputted in UTC, you can bypass the conversion to your local time zone by calling for the displayed datetime rather than the stored one:

#### Code Example:

```js
function dateConvert() {
  var d = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("A2").getDisplayValue();
  var dateObj = new Date(d);
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(dateObj, "Australia/Adelaide", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
  Logger.log(newDate);  
}
```

In this case, `newDate` will be converted to the `Australia/Adelaide` timezone.

There is also the `.getDisplayValues()` method, which works in the same way only over a range of values rather than just a single cell.

#### References:

- [Class `Range` - `getDisplayValue()` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalue)